# Why isn't my async code running async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

**WARNING** I'm a complete newbie with async/await, and so am probably misunderstanding this completely!

I'm trying to work out how this stuff works, and tried a simple bit of code in the view of a WPF window. I added a button click event handler, and added some sync and async methods as follows...

```
public partial class MainWindow {
  private Random _r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

  public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private async void Bleah_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    LstMessages.Items.Clear();
    AddToMsg("Starting...");
    DoSyncStuff();
    await DoStuffAsync();
    DoMoreStuffSync();
    AddToMsg("Done");
  }

  private void DoSyncStuff() {
    int delay = _r.Next(500, 1500);
    AddToMsg("DoSyncStuff - waiting for " + delay + "ms");
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    AddToMsg("DoSyncStuff - finished");
  }

  private void DoMoreStuffSync() {
    int delay = _r.Next(500, 1500);
    AddToMsg("DoMoreStuffSync - waiting for " + delay + "ms");
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
    AddToMsg("DoMoreStuffSync - finished");
  }

  private async Task DoStuffAsync() {
    await Task.Run(() => {
      int delay = _r.Next(500, 1500);
      AddToMsg("DoStuffAsync - waiting for " + delay + "ms");
      Thread.Sleep(delay);
      AddToMsg("DoStuffAsync - finished");
    });
  }

  private void AddToMsg(string msg) {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      new Action(() => { LstMessages.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - " + msg); }));
  }
```

`LstMessages` is a ListBox on the window.

When I click the button, I see that the three methods are always executed in the order I call them, irrespective of the length of each delay.

I'm obviously misunderstanding how this stuff works, but after reading around for a few hours, and trying lots of variations of the code, I can't get it to work how I expect.

Please can anyone clarify what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Async doesn't parallelize your code it just doesn't block the calling thread.

Comment: A good resource is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx - some of the examples should speak to your case

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep` in your async method. Use `Task.Delay` so you don't actually block the thread.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the link, but I have printed out and read that article already. I was using that, and some others in his series whilst tying to learn, but was getting stuck on the basic idea. Think I've got it now thanks to the replies here.

Comment: @mason Thanks for that, I wondered why there was such a pause before my results appeared. Using Task.Delay fixed that.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel It's a good article :)  I noticed that you were using a lot of `async void` methods in your code, which that article recommends against ("use async Task instead").  I'm glad you made some progress; I've been trying to understand async better recently myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, it appears you were kicking off an async method but immediately waiting for it in the UI thread.

```
private async void Bleah_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    LstMessages.Items.Clear();
    AddToMsg("Starting...");
    DoSyncStuff();
    Task t = DoStuffAsync();
    DoMoreStuffSync();
    await t;
    AddToMsg("Done");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both you and Will Ray helped me understand this. I wish I could mark both replies as answers. Marking yours as it came in first, and answered my question directly

Answer (score 2):

All you *have* to do is drop the `await` keyword in your code.

To quote a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one/) by Eric Lippert:

> Whenever a task is “awaited”, the remainder of the current method is signed up as a continuation of the task, and then control immediately returns to the caller. When the task completes, the continuation is invoked and the method starts up where it was before.

By adding in the `await` keyword, you're effectively saying "once this async method has completed, carry on with the rest of this method".

It might be easier to understand this with methods that return a value. The following program will start off two methods right away, and will `await` the result of the async method after it calls the sync method. You can try moving the `await` line around to watch the difference in behavior.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void MainAsync()
    {
        var task = GetNumberAsync();
        var syncNumber = GetNumber();
        var asyncNumber = await task; // moving this line above "GetNumber();" will make these run in order

        Console.WriteLine(syncNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(asyncNumber);
    }

    private static int GetNumber()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomeWork - started");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomeWork - finished");
        return 11;
    }

    private static async Task<int> GetNumberAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetNumberAsync - started");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("GetNumberAsync - finished");
        return 22;

    }
}
```

Comment: Great reply. I wish I could mark both yours and Chris's as answers, as his answered my question directly, whilst yours gave more info. Please don't be offended, but I'll probably mark his as the answer as it came in first. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand is that [`async` and `await` keywords don't cause additional threads to be created.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) (`Task.Run()` CAN move work to another thread). So what's really going on in your code?

So, in your code, the first call to `DoSyncStuff()` pauses the main thread. Your call to `DoStuffAsync()` will not even be executed until after `DoSyncStuff()` fully completes.

Your call to `DoStuffAsync` is triggered as though it's async - but because you used the await keyword in the caller function 'await DoStuffAsync()', main thread control will return to the `Bleah_Click()` caller (which for your purposes won't do anything super interesting). Once `DoStuffAsync()` completes, control returns to `Bleah_Click`, and `DoMoreStuffSync()` is executed - which again pauses your main thread.

AS to your question: I can't tell you what you've "done wrong" as you haven't really specified your desired result - if you want to pause your UI thread execution and execute all your functions in the listed order, then you've done everything right.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing makes sense, as you are performing all actions on the main UI thread. You need to either create and manage your own Thread/BackgroundWorker object, or submit a method to the ThreadPool

[BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

[Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)

[ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679040.aspx)

Each approach has its own pros and cons, which can be found in other answers here. Give these links a read and try out the examples

Comment: Those 3 approaches have quite a few cons as opposed to just using async/await properly with Task.Run, see the "Threads" section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: @thunder2709 Thanks for the reply, but I already know how to use those. I am trying to learn how to use the new features